# How to make a input slider in React that shows incremental values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I currently have an input slider with this code:

```
    
                <input
                  id="typeinp"
                  name="height"
                  type="range"
                  min="45"
                  max="80"
                  value={height}
                  valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                  step="1"
                  onChange={(e) => setHeight(e.target.value)}
                  aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
                  style={sliderStyles}
                />
```

But it doesn't show any values on the slider. So my question is, how can I get these increments on my slider like they are done here:

[image: Slider Example]

My slider currently looks like this: [image: my slider]

Comment: use already existed component or calculate increments positions and show them separately.

Comment: yeah, use already existed component. For example: https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#discrete-sliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess my question was unclear as I am new to react and didn't realize that react-native was something different from what I had. However, I was able to get the slider to work like this for anyone else who might be interested:

```
import Slider from "rc-slider";
import "rc-slider/assets/index.css";

   <Slider
              defaultValue={60}
              min={45}
              max={80}
              step={1}
              onChange={(e) => setHeight(e)}
              marks={heightMarks}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
            />
```

And the marks:

```
  const heightMarks = {
    45: "45",
    50: "50",
    55: "55",
    60: "60",
    65: "65",
    70: "70",
    75: "75",
    80: "80",
  };
```

And to install: `npm i rc-slider`

[image]